# Correct approach for combining confidence intervals from multiple estimators

Tags: normal-distribution, confidence-interval, estimators

Let's say I have an estimation from 2 different people about human population of a small town. Both are (calibrated) 90% CIs:

Expert 1: 3,000-4,000

Expert 2: 3,000-50,000 (Intentionally much wider range)

How do I combine these to have a new range that is hopefully has a higher chance of being correct (more than 90% of the time) or a narrower range while staying at 90%.